# What determines the intensity of sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics

What determines the intensity of sound? The frequency determines if it is C or #G but what does determine the loudness (aka intensity)?

Comment: Did you at-least google?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 yes I did

Comment: My point is if you did, then show your efforts; however, I'm seeing you got the answer.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 even if I did not google it this became another site that people might find the answer at.

Comment: Oh, yes; the question will come in the front page when one googles about the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intensity is a measure of the sound pressure in the wave.  The excursion from ambient pressure is greater for loud sounds.

Comment: "excursion from ambient pressure " what does the excursion mean?

Comment: Sound travels as pockets of high and low pressure. How closely packed they are is equivalent to the frequency and how high/low the pressure is in those pockets is the equivalent to the amplitude.

Comment: thnx I think I got it now